# Windows 7 Remote Control Tools

Tags: windows-7, remote-control

I used to see someone else using a Windows built-in remote control tool to connect to my Windows 7 and take over the control. I've been looking for that tool. Is it "Windows Remote Assistance" or "KRDC (Remote Desktop Client)"? Or is there any other built-in tools for remote control?

**EDIT:**

My environment:

- office at work
- on an Active Directory network

Comment: It is very much dependent on the environment you were in. Please clarify if you were on a network at work, if it was an Active Directory network if you know at all, etc. Yes, there are "Windows Remote Assitance" features. There is a Remote Desktop Client software.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [a video from Microsoft showing the use of RDC.](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/help/videos/remote-desktop-connection)

It requires Silverlight to be installed. You can also find textual instructions there.

It may help to note that KRDC use the RDP protocol which is the same as ms RDC, so a session between KRDC to ms RDC is possible (I personally haven't tried that yet though).

Answer (score 1):

If it's built into Windows, you're probably looking for [Windows Remote Assistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Remote_Assistance). KRDC is not built into Windows, it's actually built into KDE, a Linux desktop environment. KRDC would use [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) to connect to a Windows computer. Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise and Ultimate include a RDP server, and all versions of Windows 7 include a native RDP client called "Remote Desktop Connection" (`mstsc.exe`).

The difference is, remote desktop would give them complete control. In fact, you can't even see your screen because only one person can be logged into one account at any time. Someone connecting using remote desktop would log you out (and would need your username and password). Remote assistance allows you to see the screen, see what they are doing and retain control - they only have what permissions you grant.

Comment: I think I am looking for something more like Remote assistance. Since last time I was viewing my desktop with another guy and we both have control to the desktop.

Comment: @Stan - Remote assistance is built into Windows since I believe Windows XP.